# How do I stack one navigation menu on top other the other using z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am a bit stuck trying to place or stack two navigation menus on top of each other, I am using Bootstrap, HTML and CSS.

I think I might need to use the `z-index`, but not sure exactly how.

I have added the code below and included picture of what I would like to achieve.

Code:

```
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-white navbar-white">
    <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#">
    <img src="assets/logo2.png"height="84px">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="accessability">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="contrast">Contrast</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Font-size">Font size</a>
        </li>
        <li class="download">Download a brochure</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">New Vehicles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nearly New/ Used Vehicles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Motability</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aftercare</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary">
  <ul>
      <li class="sec-menu">Versa Connect</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="sec-menu"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="sec-menu"><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
          <li class="sec-menu"><a href="#">Models</a></li>
            <li class="sec-menu"><a href="#">Optional Extras</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
  <section id="cover_image">
    <div class="container">
 <img src="assets/cover_image.jpg" >
 <div class="text-block">
   <h1>Versa Connect</h1>
   <p>The Ford Torneo Connect is a relaxing and comfortable place to be.
   Great to drive, great to sit in, it boasts premium finish, high quality materials
 and fuel efficiency without compromising everyday practicality. </p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Make an enquiry</button>
 </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1{
  font-family: roboto;
}

p{
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
}
li{
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  display:inline;

  padding: 30px;
}

li a{
  color: #000;
}
.navbar-right{
  float: right !important;
  margin-right: -15px;
  display: inline;
}
ul.nav navbar-nav navbar-right li a{
  display: flex;
}
li.sec-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: roboto;
}
.container{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.text-block {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 100px;

  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  color:#000;
  width: 380px;
  padding:50px;
}
.btn btn-lg btn-primary{
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 360px;
}
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with my coding and show me how or where I should code the `z-index` in my code.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Code or picture not included :)

Comment: where is the code picture?

Comment: check now, thank you.

Comment: I have been looking online and wondering if the z-index is the correct element to use.

Answer (score 1):

The z-index property is used for stacking items on top of each other via the z plane (think of a 3-dimensional plane), so that property would not help you here. All you need to do is create each navbar using a separate "nav" or "div" tag, which will put them on separate lines.

You are on the right track, but you have multiple errors in your code that are causing this issue. Your navbar consisting of "Contrast, Font Size, Download a Brochure" have closing anchor tags but not beginning anchor tags. This navbar is also using a class "accessability" that is not defined in your CSS, which is why it's appearing as an unstyled unordered list.

Here is a simple version of what you are looking for:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Contrast</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Font Size</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Download a Brochure</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">New Vehicles</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Nearly New/Used Vehicles</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Motability</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Aftercare</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One other thing, I am using Bootstrap menus , so how would that go?- I guess I need to do some playing around. Many thanks again.

Comment: You can do it the same way, just replace my simple navbar components with the bootstrap navbar components. Here is a codepen of how it would work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMbZxN.

Comment: ok not quite there yet. Top menu is great - but lower menu having difficulty placing it correctly.

Comment: yeah, that bottom menu just isn't going where I want it.

Comment: No this isnt working for me!! I think I have have something wrong with the names or {ul} in the code. Not sure

Comment: Here's a codepen using the the CSS you originally provided with slightly modified HTML: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMbZxN. I would look into CSS flexbox for an issue like this, then you would be able to use very simplified code like in my original post. Bootstrap can get very messy because of the large number of classes used in components.

Comment: I appreciate that i am trying to make this page mobile first by using Bootstrap. -the menus/ navigation are all over the place. I have been following your code and trying to find where I have errors in my code and correct them but without luck. the "accessibility" menu does exactly what i want it to do, the the lower nav, I just cant get it to go underneath and horizontal. - I will keep on trying.

Answer (score 1):

This works, you do not need the z-index. You can view it here on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rvdgaq

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-white navbar-white">
    <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#">
         <img src="assets/logo2.png"height="84px">
    </a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

 <ul class="accessability">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="contrast">Contrast</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Font-size">Font size</a>
    </li>
    <li class="download">Download a brochure</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">New Vehicles</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nearly New/ Used Vehicles</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Motability</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aftercare</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary">
  <ul>
      <li class="nav-item sec-menu">Versa Connect</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item sec-menu"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item sec-menu"><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item sec-menu"><a href="#">Models</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item sec-menu"><a href="#">Optional Extras</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

  </div>

</div>
 <section id="cover_image">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <img src="assets/cover_image.jpg" >
 <div class="text-block">
<h1>Versa Connect</h1>
<p>The Ford Torneo Connect is a relaxing and comfortable place to be.
   Great to drive, great to sit in, it boasts premium finish, high quality materials
 and fuel efficiency without compromising everyday practicality. </p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Make an enquiry</button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
 </section>
```

A Few things I noticed, 1. You did not close off your section tag so that could be causing issues. And you do not need postion: absolute; on .text-block, take off bottom: 10px;

Make it position relative

Comment: No my navs are all over the place at the moment.